# Update confluence page via API call - Provided value {{id}} for 'id' is not the correct type. Expected type is long

Tags: node.js, confluence

My goal is to update a given confluence page using Nodejs code but faced an issue as title of the post says. Full error response received is shown below.

### My attempt

```
// Function to update Confluence page
function updateConfluencePage(pageId, newContent) {
    getCurrentPageVersion(pageId, (error, versionNumber) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error retrieving page version:', error);
            return;
        }

        const bodyData = `{
          "id": '${pageId}',
          "status": "current",
          "title": "",
          "body": {
            "representation": "storage",
            "value": ${newContent}
          },
          "version": {
            "number": ${versionNumber + 1},
            "message": ""
          }
        }`;
        const options = {
            url: `${constants.JIRA_BASE_URL}/wiki/api/v2/pages/{id}`,
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(
                    constants.CONFLUENCE_USERNAME + ":" + constants.CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD
                ).toString('base64')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: bodyData
        };
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                console.log(`Response: ${response.statusCode} ${response.statusMessage}`);
                console.log(body);
            }
        }); 
    });

}
```

### Response received

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "status": 400,
        "code": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
        "title": "Provided value {{id}} for 'id' is not the correct type. Expected type is long.",
        "detail": null
    }
]
```

}

What does "Expected type is long" mean ?